# How to not pass empty number input fields in HTML form

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using code like this, that I found from here, that prevents empty fields from submitting. The forms class is remove-empty-field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.remove-empty-fields').submit(function() {
$(this).find(':input').filter(function()
{ return !this.value; }).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
return true; // make sure that the form is still submitted
});
});
```

I would like to change it so only empty number fields don't get submitted but empty text fields do. It would make submitted email more standard looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input fields values are strings, so your option is to know which input is which type and treat them differently. You can do this by the ID of the input, for example.

Another option is to put `type="number"` on your number inputs and treat them differently because of that, so for each empty `input[type="number"]`, don't submit anything, but for the rest do.
So your filter function would look like this:

```
return !this.value && this.type === "number"
```

Comment: what will returning `this.type ==="number"` do ? will it convert the input fields to type 'number'

Comment: No, it simply checks the the input element is of type "number", which means the input looks like `<input type="number">`

Comment: so it will only return something if `<input type ="number">` exists. what about `!this.value`

Comment: It will check that the input is empty.

Comment: thanks a lot. it would return true for each case then only we will disable the field. am I right ?